# I want the short the person based on the post,but it is showing an error that, `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want the short the person based on the post,but it is showing an error that, `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)

```
merchant = Hash.new

BusinessOwner.each{|owner|
  if !owner.phoneNumber.blank? && !owner.phoneNumber.phoneNumber.blank? && !owner.phoneNumber.phoneNumber.include?("-reset") 
    merchant["name"] = owner.name
    merchant["phone"] = owner.phoneNumber.countryCode.to_s + owner.phoneNumber.phoneNumber.to_s
    merchant["post"] = owner.account.items.count
    puts merchant                               
  end
}
result = merchant.sort_by{|k| k['post']}.reverse
result.first
```

Comment: You're always updating the `merchant` instance, you will have to create an array and add a new instance of `merchant` to it in the `each` loop.

Comment: how to do it,can you please help me creating an array and sorting it

Comment: oK,thanks for the help

Comment: The basic setup is `arr = []` and in the each loop you add the merchant to this loop `merchant = {}; arr << merchant` and then sort it `arr.sort_by ... `

Comment: Thank you ,i found out it was a silly mistake